# Editar dados de um array

Tags: php

Tenho esse array abaixo:

```
    <?php

//Rio de Janeiro
$planoResidencialRjo = array(

array("nome" => "25MB Residencial", "cidade" => "Rio de Janeiro", "download" => "25MB", "upload" => "1MB", "tipo" => "Residencial", "valor" => "R$ 89,90", "fidelidade" => "R$ 69,90"),
array("nome" => "30MB Residencial", "cidade" => "Rio de Janeiro", "download" => "30MB", "upload" => "1MB", "tipo" => "Residencial","valor" => "R$ 99,90" , "fidelidade" => "R$ 79,90"),
array("nome" => "40MB Residencial", "cidade" => "Rio de Janeiro", "download" => "40MB", "upload" => "1MB", "tipo" => "Residencial", "valor" => "R$ 109,90", "fidelidade" => "R$ 89,90"),
array("nome" => "50MB Residencial", "cidade" => "Rio de Janeiro", "download" => "50MB", "upload" => "1MB", "tipo" => "Residencial", "valor" => "R$ 119,90", "fidelidade" => "R$ 99,90"),
);

$planoComercialRjo = array(

array("nome" => "40MB Residencial", "cidade" => "Rio de Janeiro", "download" => "40MB", "upload" => "upload de até 10% da velocidade de download", "tipo" => "Residencial", "valor" => "R$ 109,90", "fidelidade" => "R$ 89,90"),
array("nome" => "60MB Residencial", "cidade" => "Rio de Janeiro", "download" => "60MB", "upload" => "upload de até 10% da velocidade de download", "tipo" => "Residencial", "valor" => "R$ 119,90", "fidelidade" => "R$ 99,90"),
array("nome" => "100MB Residencial", "cidade" => "Rio de Janeiro", "download" => "100MB", "upload" => "upload de até 5% da velocidade de download", "tipo" => "Residencial", "valor" => "R$ 139,90", "fidelidade" => "R$ 119,90"),

);
```

> Preciso criar um outro arquivo *PHP* que me permita modificar esses
>   dados facilmente em um formulário simples,  qual seria meus primeiros
>   passos ?

Comment: Você está usando banco de dados ou não?

Comment: to nao amigo, é um arquivo de array puro recentemente criado

Comment: Bom então tira o "facilmente"... rs o unico jeito de fazer isso sem banco é criando um formulário html com os campos de cada dado que vc tem no array e esse formulario a action dele ser um arquivo php q manipule esses dados inicia um `ob_start()` e transforme estes dados neste código que está na sua pergunta recebendo os valoes aos seus respectivos lugares no array e em seguida pegar o conteudo do buffer com `ob_get_clean()` e jogar em um arquivo php com `file_put_contents()`... e fazer isso é meio chato e fica meio feio também sabe... kkk